# Overlay divs using Jquery Supersized

Tags: jquery, css

How can i set the div with id mainholder that holds my header and all data overlays the div with id overmainholder?

I am using Jquery Supersized for my full screen bg.
I tried everything but my mainholder div with header etc goes backwords overmainholder!

**Inside Body:**

```
<div id="overmainholder"></div>
<div id="mainholder">
<div id="header"></div>
</div>
```

**My css**

```
#mainholder{
    width:1051px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:100;
}

#overmainholder{
width:100%;
height:202px;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
float:left;
z-index:2;
background-image:url(../images/bodybg.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#header{
width:1051px;
height:202px;
background-image:url(../images/headerbg.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:101;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header is nested and mainholder is not absolute position so you cannot set z-index.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking but here's my suggestion:

1. Css for mainholder:

   ```
   #mainholder{
       width:1051px;
       height:700px;
       margin:0 auto;
   }
   ```
2. CSS for overmainholder (note z-index is -1)

   ```
   #overmainholder{
       width:100%;
       height:202px;
       position: absolute;
       top:0;
       left:0;
       z-index: -1;
       background-image:url(../images/bodybg.jpg);
       background-repeat:repeat-x;
   }
   ```

This will put mainholder on top.